# Edit terminal colors in WebStorm integrated terminal?

Tags: terminal, webstorm

Does anyone know how to change the colors for the integrate terminal in WebStorm?

Currently it looks like this for me:
[image: Windows 10]

Which makes it super hard to see directory names.

If I could just have directories be a different color with no background or just bold text with no background. The key is I don't need my directories to have a background.

This is how it looks on Windows 10 using `bash.exe`. I can't currently show what it looks like when running outside of WebStorm, but I can show what it looks like on OSX as I'm having a similar issue:

OSX WebStorm with Material Theme plugin using `/bin/zsh`:
[image: OSX]

vs `zsh` in iTerm:
[image: iTerm]

I'm mostly curious if there is a way to maybe turn off the Material Theme for just the integrated terminal or edit the colors directly there? If need be I can just use the external terminal, but it'd be nice to use the integrated one if I could just read all the text.

Comment: what OS is it, what shell is configured as a terminal in *Settings | Tools | Terminal*? What is a result of running the same command in this shell (outside of the IDE)?

Comment: Edited my question to provide more details. Couldn't show the Windows 10 version since I'm at work, but I'm having a similar coloration problem with OSX so I've added pictures for that.